# How to generate a unique barcode without using identity or sequence in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

We're currently building an application where customers need to have 1 unique barcode. Each time a new customer has been added to the system, a new unique barcode needs to be generated for that customer.

We're using 12 digits for this barcode, but the first 6 digits are fixed, leaving me with only 6 digits left to generate a unique number.

At first I wanted to do this based on the primary key of the table `customer`, which is an `identity` column. And this would have worked prior to SQL Server 2012 because apparently, whenever the SQL Server 2012 service gets (forcefully) restarted, the `identity` column jumps by 1000 or 10000 (depending on the datatype of your column), which would skyrocket the amount of digits being used, risking to exceed the 6 digit limit. Same with the `Sequence` functionality.

Can anyone point me out how you would do it? I've been thinking of storing a number myself in a column with a unique constraint and add 1 to it each time a customer has been added but this makes me feel very uncomfortable.

Thanks for reading this far, any advice is appreciated.

Zeep

Comment: How often do you get new customers?

Comment: @Vérace unfortunately I cannot say how often new customers will be added to the system. I'm expecting a lot of insertions during the first months of usage and then it will probably drop to a relatively lower amount. Are you asking this to determine the chance of having a conflict?

Comment: Yes - for some people, 10 customers a day would be huge (car dealer), but not for Walmart! :-). Try Googling "sql server gapless sequences" - I saw a few things which might be of interest to you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you feel uncomfortable storing the id yourself?
This is a valid approach for this problem.

You could also use -T272 as a startup parameter to prevent the gaps during id generation.
I read that this could have impact on the performance of the id generation, but I never had no problems in my tests.
See this link for further information: http://www.dfarber.com/computer-consulting-blog/2014/2/13/how-to-solve-identity-problem-in-sql-2012.aspx

Please consider that there are many different types of barcodes. If you use the common GS1-128 for example, you can create alpha-numeric codes to increase the possible combinations and prevent an overflow.

Comment: I won't be using the -T272 startup parameter because I don't want to mess around too much with the SQL server. But you're right, I'll just store the ID myself. Thanks.